# Using Html.DropDownList with View Component

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, razor

I would like to create a dropdown list within a view component in my ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC app.

I need to display more than one model in the same view, so I'm using view components. I have tried partial views, but had some trouble with them. I've been referring to [this documentation.](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-2.2)

- The model I'm using in the view component is `Tag`.
- The view component is `TagListViewComponent`
- The view that invokes the view component is `Edit.cshtml`. (This view uses a different model, `Post`, which is why I'm invoking the view component to accecss the `Tag` model.)
- The view component Razor page is `Default.cshtml`
- I don't think there are any routing issues, because I can successfully render each `Tag` in the view:

```
public class Tag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
}

public class TagListViewComponent : ViewComponent
{
    private readonly Website.Data.ApplicationDbContext db;
    public TagListViewComponent(Website.Data.ApplicationDbContext context)
    {
        db = context;
    }

    public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
    {
        var tag = await db.Tag.ToListAsync();
        return View(tag);
    }
}
```

**Views:**

Edit.cshtml

```
// (using a different model and removing irrelevant HTML)
<div>
    @await  Component.InvokeAsync("TagList")
</div>
```

Default.cshtml

```
@model IEnumerable<Website.Models.Tag>
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    @Html.ActionLink(item.Title, "Details", "Tags", new { item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-outline-primary btn-sm" })
    <br />
}
```

The above code renders the six tags listed in the database when I navigate to a page using `edit.cshtml`, e.g., `https://localhost:xxxxx/Posts/Edit/2`.

The problem I'm having is that I can't for the life of me figure out how to display the tags in a dropdown list. I can add to the `Default.cshtml` view the following:

```
@Html.DropDownList("Title", new SelectList(Model))
```

This does create a dropdown list, with six options (which is the correct number), but all options say `Website.Models.Tag`. I'm unable to access the `Tag.Title` property or any other properties.

I've also tried `@Html.DropDownListFor()`, but it doesn't let me access any properties either.

In the `TagListViewComponent.cs`, I've tried including more info (`PostTags` is a navigation property of `Tag`, and it contains a `tag` property which links back to the tags...). But the below code just provides the same level of access as the original `InvokeAsync` method:

```
public async Task<IViewComponentResult> InvokeAsync()
{
   var tag = await db.Tag
            .Include(t => t.PostTags)
            .ThenInclude(pt => pt.tag)
            .ToListAsync();
   return View(tag);
}
```

I haven't been able to find any information about using dropdown lists with view components. Any direction would be very appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create an `IEnumerable<SelectListItem>` from your model and pass that into `@Html.DropDownList("Title", selectListItems)`

```
var selectListItems = Model
    .Select(tag => new SelectListItem{ Text = tag.Title, Value = tag.Id });
```

Comment: Fantastic. If anyone else sees this, I had to add the `[NotMapped]` attribute to `public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> selectListItems { get; set; }` in my model (as no primary key was defined). Thank you.